# add real dates to the X-axis of a drawdown plot

Tags: matplotlib, timestamp

I am trying to incorporate timestamps/real dates to the X-axis of a drawdown plot. I got this block of code from a post I saw earlier

```
n = 1000
xs = np.random.randn(n).cumsum()
i = np.argmax(np.maximum.accumulate(xs) - xs) # end of the period
j = np.argmax(xs[:i]) # start of period

plt.plot(xs)
plt.plot([i, j], [xs[i], xs[j]], 'o', color='Red', markersize=10)
```

The question is the input of this block of code has to be NumPy array type. But in reality where you look at a drawdown, you may also want to look at it in a real time frame. How do I incorporate or maybe just add the date of the beginning and the end of a whole experimentation period (not just the beginning and end of a drawdown)? Thank you!

Comment: So you want to add a label with the date at the two markers?

Comment: Not only that, but kind of more importantly, the start and end of the whole thing, the whole backtesting period such that when you look at it, you understand 'oh, in a five -year run from 2015 to 2020 (start to end), there is a max drawdown that starts in May of 2016 and ends in Sep of 2016. Basically the timing/dates of milestone events, so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code as a starting point:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
plt.close()

# period n
n = 100
xs = np.random.randn(n).cumsum()
i = np.argmax(np.maximum.accumulate(xs) - xs) # end of the period
j = np.argmax(xs[:i]) # start of period

# start date and populating period n with dates
now = dt.datetime.now()
then = now + dt.timedelta(days=n)
days = mdates.drange(now, then, dt.timedelta(days=1))

# actual plot
plt.plot(days, xs, color="blue")
plt.plot([days[i], days[j]], [xs[i], xs[j]], 'o', color='Red', markersize=10)

# point labels
plt.annotate("end", (days[i], xs[i]))
plt.annotate("start", (days[j], xs[j]))

# vertical lines
plt.axvline(x=days[i], color="black")
plt.axvline(x=days[j], color="black")

# sets x-axis up for dates
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=10))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

This gives:

[image: plot]

You can modify the point labels in `.annotate()` to represent that particular date as well. By changing the variable `now` to a particular datetime, you can set start date. Change the `interval=10` value to choose frequency of xticks on x-axis of dates.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect! One thing though: how would you plot a designated series of dates then? In this example you gave here, the dates simply go day by day whereas in reality you only have stock prices on business days. I've been trying to set the "dates" up in a way it equals the index of the pandas series. It never worked.

Comment: What you can do is look for data that already has dates and use that as the dataframe. Or you could delete the days you do not want from a list of all dates. Please accept the answer if it has solved your original question. :)

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I have "upvoted" the answer. Does it not count as "approval' or "acceptance"?

Comment: This is what an [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) answer is.

Comment: "Checked" I have!